# Integration Using Tables

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve the following integral via table substitution.

$$\int\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin^2{x}-9}\space dx$$

[These tables](http://integral-table.com/downloads/single-page-integral-table.pdf) look a little different from my book, but they're more or less identical. First, I check out the trig integral forms, which start at #63 in the tables I linked.

I don't see any integrals in this section that have trig rational forms, so that leads me to believe that this equation will require some manipulation to get it to fit one of the forms.

I could easily integrate a $cos{x}$ but the denominator gets in the way. I don't even see anything in the tables that could integrate anything in the form $\sin^n-a$.

Which of the trig substitutions in the table I linked help to solve this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we put $u = \sin x$, then $\,du = \cos x \,dx$.

This gives you an integral of the form $$\int \frac{du}{u^2 - 9} = \int \frac{du}{u^2 - (3)^2}$$

Does that look more familiar?

See [trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) (substitution $(3)$): put $u = 3\sec\theta$.

Comment: thanks; now that you write it like that, I can see that it matches #32 on the tables.